# what does this shell script codes means

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, tar

i need some help to understand the following few lines of a given shell script.

here `$_filecount` variable hold the number of file to be archived

here i want to know what `$TARC` means, searched on this command but got no result for `TARC` and `TARU` commands. could anybody explain me what these commands are

```
_archive=${ARCHIVE_PATH}/${_name}_$(hostname)_${_today}.tar


if [ $_filecount -ne 0 ]; then
      if ! [ -f ${_archive} ]; then
        touch ${ARCHIVE_PATH}/${_today}
        $TARC ${_archive} -C ${ARCHIVE_PATH} ${_today}
        rm -f ${ARCHIVE_PATH}/${_today}
      fi
      for i in ${_filelist}; do

        $TARU ${_archive} -C ${_path} $i
        [ $? -eq 0 ] && rm -f ${_path}/$i
      done
    fi
```

when this code is run using `cygwin`  at line $TARC `${_archive} -c ${ARCHIVE_PATH} ${_today}` returns following error

```
tar: invalid option -- 'E'
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
```

thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Try to echo `_archive` and see how it looks. It might be that you have spaces in it that makes the input to `tar` invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$TARC` and `$TARU` are variables (if they aren't defined in your script somewhere, then they must be environment variables)

Try `echo $TARC` to see what they are set to.

Looks TARC is the tar command to archive and TARU is the tar command to unarchive.

TARC and TARU must be set somewhere or else you would get a different error - the error you are seeing is tar specific.

Comment: ok, as you said TARC is "tar -cvf", it is defined in the script, so do you know why this error is returned